# Como não filtrar apenas uma pasta em JAVA - Filter

Tags: java, jsp, filter

Estou usando uma classe herdada de `Filter` em Java para fazer o controle de login.

Eu fiz o mapeamento no `Web.xml` da seguinte forma:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ValidacaoLoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>br.com.dgtbr.configuracao.ValidacaoLoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ValidacaoLoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/sistema/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

O meu problema é que eu quero que só as páginas `.JSP` caiam no filtro, porém não consigo colocar a `url-pattern` da seguinte forma:

```
.....
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ValidacaoLoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/sistema/*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Deployment is in progress...
>   deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FLeonardo%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext4308821743855259488.xml&path=/DGTBr.
>   FAIL - Deployed application at context path ... but context failed to start
>   ......nbproject\build-impl.xml:1163: O módulo não foi implantado.
>   Verifique o log do servidor para ver mais detalhes.

Em resumo, dentro da pasta `/sistema/` eu tenho uma outra pasta que **não** quero que passe pelo `Filter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A API do java não permite especificar esse tipo de padrão. Infelizmente, existem apenas três formas: pelo caminho exato, caminho com um `*` ao final, extensão.

Adicionalmente, você pode aplicar o filtro a um Servlet usando a tag `<servlet-name>` ao invés do `<url-pattern>`.

A forma mais simples e direta de contornar o problema é colocar todos os arquivos `.jsp` em uma pasta separada e mapear pela pasta.

Outro *workaround* é mapear pela pasta e então colocar uma condição, aplicando o processamento desejado apenas de a extensão do recurso requisitado for `.jsp`.

Soluções mais complexas, porém mais poderosas e flexíveis, incluem usar um framework como o Google Guice, que possui uma [API de filtros para Servlet](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletRegexKeyMapping) que funciona como uma extensão da API original. Praticamente todo framework web vai possuir algum tipo de API para colocar um *interceptor* ou *filter* mais personalizado.

Comment: a parte de mapear em outra pasta deu certo. Porém continue procurando na net e achei o modo de tratar meio que manualmente no Filter mesmo. Achei legal e ajuda bastante. Segue o link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125296/can-i-exclude-some-concrete-urls-from-url-pattern-inside-filter-mapping.

E valeu pela ajuda. tks.

Comment: @lionbtt Esse link é uma implementação do *workaround* proposta na resposta. Mas o invés de usar o método `endsWith` para verificar a extensão ao invés do caminho ele usa `startsWith` para verificar a pasta.